# change isActive on click

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this widget list for a profile list and it looks like this

[image]

Here is the code for this. I am a bit new,any help is appreciate

```
Widget _buildProfileList() {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          _buildProfileItem('AA', '+99 90 111 11 11', true),
          _buildProfileItem('BB', '+99 90 222 22 22', false),
          _buildAddProfileButton(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildProfileItem(String name, String phone, bool isActive) {
    return Card(
      color: Colors.white,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        side: BorderSide(color: isActive ? Colors.green : Colors.grey, width: 2),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      child: ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.person),
        title: Text(name),
        subtitle: Text(phone),
        trailing: isActive ? Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.green) : null,
      ),
      onPressed: (){

      },
    );
  }
```

So I am passing the function an `bool isActive` and according to that it looks as if selected or not. What I want to do is, If I press any other child inside `ListView()` I want the active one to change, as it should be.

Yet if I try to add `onPressed :(){}` it returns an error saying `The parameter onPressed is not defined` and this is for `Card()` I think.

even if it was defined, how can I change the `isActive` one as I wished after clicking the button?

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable named `selectedIndex`. When a list tile is selected change this value in `_buildProfileItem` pass an index. Compare this index with the selected Item as follows

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: Home()));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int selectedIndex = 0;//This variable will hold which item is selected
//change it to index in place of bool
  Widget _buildProfileItem(String name, String phone, int index) {
    return Card(
      color: Colors.white,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        side: BorderSide(
            color: selectedIndex == index ? Colors.green : Colors.grey,
            width: 2),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      child: ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.person),
        title: Text(name),
        subtitle: Text(phone),
        trailing: selectedIndex == index
            ? Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.green)
            : null,
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            selectedIndex = index;
//set the index on tap of the list tile.
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
      children: [
        _buildProfileItem('AA', '+99 90 111 11 11', 0),
        _buildProfileItem('BB', '+99 90 222 22 22', 1),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain index or some identifier of the `ListTile` item that  is active( which means the one clicked by user or initially selected).

`Card` doesn't have onPressed parameter hence the error. You have to move the onPressed function to `ListTile`.

Say you decide to use the phone as an identifier, you can do something like follows:

1. variable declaration

```
    String isActive='either-phone-number';
```

either-phone-number is one phone number you decide to show as selected dy default. If none then pass ''( empty string) .

2. on tap function

```
onPressed: ()=>
setState(()=> isActive ='listtile-phone-number')
,
```

listtile-phone-number is the number passed to the `ListTile`.

3. isActive condition

```
isActive=='listtile-phone-number'?Icon():null,
```